# Finding the maximum value of every row in 2D array C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, max

I've managed to find the minimum value of every row of my 2D array with this

```
void findLowest(int A[][Cm], int n, int m)
{
    int min = A[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
         {
             if (A[i][j] < min)
             {
                 min = A[i][j];
             }
         }
     out << i << " row's lowest value " << min << endl;
    }
}
```

I'am trying to find the maximum value of every row using the same way,but it only shows me first maximum value

```
void findHighest(int A[][Cm], int n, int m)
{
     int max = A[0][0];
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
         {
             if (A[i][j] > max)
             {
                max = A[i][j];
             }
         }
     out << i << " row's highest value " << max << endl;
     }
}
```

I can't find what's wrong with the second function and why is it only showing me the first maximum value it finds. Any help ?

Comment: Your first example only finds the minimum element in the entire array.

Comment: If your have a solution for the min, why don't you just take A * -1 and run that through your function? There's a good chance your min is wrong if a few simple substitutions doesn't turn it into a max.

Comment: these codes dont "show" anything. both functions are void !

Comment: By "showing" I meant when I put `out << ` or `cout << ` inside of them. Code updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both functions return the result (maximum or minimum) for the whole array rather than each row, because you set `max` once rather than once per row. You can get the result for each row as follows:

```
void findHighest(int A[][Cm], int n, int m)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         int max = A[i][0];
         for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
         {
             if (A[i][j] > max)
             {
                max = A[i][j];
             }
         }
         // do something with max
     }
}
```

or, even better, use the standard library function [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element):

```
void findHighest(int A[][Cm], int n, int m)
{
     if (m <= 0) return;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         int max = *std::max_element(A[i], A[i] + m);
         // do something with max
     }
}
```

This should give you all values which is easy to check:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

enum { Cm = 2 };

void findHighest(int A[][Cm], int n, int m) {
  if (m <= 0) return;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int max = *std::max_element(A[i], A[i] + m);
    std::cout << max << " ";
  }
}

int main() {
  int A[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  findHighest(A, 2, 2);
}
```

prints `2 4`.

Comment: Ummm, but it shows me all minimum values. That's what I get in the result file if I add `out << i << " row's minimum value << min << endl;` after the inner loop : 0 row's lowest value 46
1 row's lowest value 41
2 row's lowest value 36
3 row's lowest value 31
4 row's lowest value 26 By the way, I don't want to use the `max_element` function.

Comment: almost +1 for using the standard algorithm `max_element`, but you don't handle the pathalogical case of m being 0. This will result in UB when you assign to `max`.

Comment: @feco. Isn't it what you are trying to get, minimum (or maximum) in each row?

Comment: @RichardHodges Added a check, thanks. Anyway this is only an example.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to get,but what bothers me is that the first function shows me all minimum values and the second function only shows me the first maximum value,whilst both of them using the same way of finding values.

Answer (score 4):

If your compiler supports C++11, for concrete arrays you could use the following alternative, that's based on [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void
minmax_row(T const (&arr)[N][M], T (&mincol)[N], T (&maxcol)[N]) {
  for(int i(0); i < N; ++i) {
    auto mnmx = std::minmax_element(std::begin(arr[i]), std::end(arr[i]));
    if(mnmx.first != std::end(arr[i]))  mincol[i] = *(mnmx.first);
    if(mnmx.second != std::end(arr[i])) maxcol[i] = *(mnmx.second);
  }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/019a96241bdc6ab0)

Comment: This is great but the OP is not asking how to find min and max simultaneously.

Comment: @vitaut it's not the answer to the OP. It's an alternative solution. Future readers may benefit from it. It wouldn't feel right if I'd answered  a question that it had already been answered ;).

Comment: @101010 There's a small typo in your live demo at line 15; an extra square bracket ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your test data is guilty for not clearly showing you the defect.

The row minima occur in decreasing values, so that they get updated on every row.

And the row maxima also occur in decreasing values, so that the first one keeps winning.

As others pointed, your function finds the global minimum/maximum, no the per-row extrema.

Move the initialization of the min/max variable inside the outer loop.

Comment: I've checked it. Thanks for pointing it out, that seems to be the issue.

Comment: You said it in a comment: the row minima are 46, 41, 36, 31, 26, decreasing. I don't know about the row maxima. Maybe you can consider an upvote ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust +1 for pointing to the reason of the 'discrepancy'.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned your code only shows the maximum element in the whole array.
Here is the code which will help you.

```
 void findHighest(int A[][Cm], int n, int m)
 {
    int max[n];
    max[0]=A[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      {
         if (A[i][j] > max[i])
         {
            max[i] = A[i][j];
         }
     }
  cout << i << " row's highest value " << max[i] << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{

```
int i,j;

int arr[4][2]={(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)};
int max;
max=arr[0][0];

for( int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        if(max<arr[i][j])
        {
            max=arr[i][j];

        }

    }

}

int min;
min=arr[0][0];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        if(min>arr[i][j])
        {
            min=arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

cout<<"maximum number is:"<<max;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Minimum Number is:"<<min;
```

}

Comment: Can you give a short description?