# Min/max element of 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

```
float allmin[column];
float allmax[column];
float min= std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
float max= std::numeric_limits<float>::min();  

for(int y = 0; y < column; y++)
   {

    for(int x = 0; x < row; x++)
       {
         allmin[y] = std::min(matrix[x][y], min);
         allmax[y] = std::max(matrix[x][y], max);
       }

   cout << "Mins " << allmin[y] << "\n";
}
```

I need the smallest element of each column. My matrix is 250x6 , what it prints is the last row of the matrix.

Comment: its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210401/finding-the-maximum-value-of-every-row-in-2d-array-c

Comment: Inside the row loop, you need to update min and max, rather than allmin and allmax, because min and max are always just staying the same max and min float values.  Then, after the the inner loop, update allmin and allmax with the values from min and max.  Also, make sure you initiaize min and max inside the outer loop, so they don't carry through with previous columns' values.

Comment: Initialize min max in first loop: min  = matrix[0][y]; max = matrix[0][y];

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::min();` is the smallest positive float.  It would make more sense to use either `0` (if your data is non-negative), or `-std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two corrections:

Do not use the same variable for each of your columns, but a different one, like directly your `allmin` and `allmax` row.

Initialize it before entering the loop. A classic solution is to initialize it with the first element of the row and to check every next one in your loop.

```
for(int y = 0; y < column; y++)
   {
    allmin[y] = matrix[0][y];
    allmax[y] = matrix[0][y];
    for(int x = 1; x < row; x++)
       {
         allmin[y] = std::min(matrix[x][y], allmin[y]);
         allmax[y] = std::max(matrix[x][y], allmax[y]);
       }

   cout << "Mins " << allmin[y] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It returns values that do not exist in the matrix though. I got values from 1 to 5000 with 2 floating points and it returns Mins 7.18866e-43
Mins 0
Mins -7.85255e+06
Mins 4.57692e-41
Mins 1.68436e-42
Mins 3.05483e-43

Answer (score 0):

Because statement `allmin[y] = std::min(matrix[x][y], min);`, the `matrix[x][y] is always small than`min(std::numeric_limits::max())`, so when internal loop execute,`allmin[y]`is updated to ·matrix[x][y]` every times, so at last `allmin[y]` is updated to `matrix[259][y]`(the last column of `y` row).
`allmax[y] = std::max(matrix[x][y], max);` has the same question.

you should change your code to
```
    float allmin[column];
    float allmax[column];
    float min= std::numeric_limits::max();
    float max= std::numeric_limits::min();

```
for(int y = 0; y < column; y++)
{
    allmin[y] = min
    allmax[y] = max
    for(int x = 0; x < row; x++)
    {
         allmin[y] = std::min(matrix[x][y], allmin[y]); //allmin[y] always store the min value has meet before
         allmax[y] = std::max(matrix[x][y], allmax[y]); //allmax[y] always store the max value has meet before
   }

   cout << "Mins " << allmin[y] << "\n";
}
```

That everything will be ok